# How to lock my Ubuntu for a specific amount of time

Tags: ubuntu, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}; do 
    timeout 1 gnome-screensaver-command -l
done
```

Running this as a one-line command in the terminal (without `#!/bin/bash`) will keep locking  my pc for 10 seconds, and unlocking it is impossible. This is desired.

However, when I run this via script, it only locks it once, but after that I can immediately unlock and use the pc. Please help me.. I want to automate it and use it as a cron job. How to make it work?

This is all I have in my cron file:

```
1 * * * * for i in {1..5}; do timeout --foreground 1 gnome-screensaver-command -l; done > test
```

It won't even run the job. No test file appears. When I run `service cron status`, no job is run recently, even though I commanded it to run the script every minute..

Answer (score 1):

A bigger question is why are you running the command 10 times for 1 second, instead of 1 time for 10 seconds? You wouldn't even need the loop then. If it's to stop someone else from entering the password and unlocking the computer, maybe you should just change the password and keep it to yourself.

---

There's software to help manage time, you might want to try one, like [Pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/):

> This GNOME app helps to manage time according to [Pomodoro Technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_technique). It intends to improve productivity and quality of work by reminding you to take short breaks.
>
> Pomodoro Technique is based on two principles:
>
> - focusing on work for limited time, about half an hour,
> - clearing your mind during breaks.
>
> This workflow can improve focus, physical health and mental agility depending on how you spend your breaks and how strictly you follow the routine.

[image]

[image]

See this question on askubuntu [Is there a Pomodoro app available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158261/is-there-a-pomodoro-app-available), it also recommends [tomate](https://github.com/eliostvs/tomate-gtk) among others.

---

If you wanted to "stop" a particular program for a while, you could use `kill -STOP pid`, or `pkill -STOP pattern`, as in

```
kill -STOP pid
sleep $seconds
kill -CONT pid
```

Stopping whatever program you want to take a break from would let the rest of the system keep working. I wouldn't really want to try stopping something more major, like the window manager or X/xorg.

---

Cron doesn't behave exactly like your regular user's terminal does, it might not even know where some commands are. You could try:

- Running the command as your user, via `sudo -u [YourUser] command` (see man sudo for more info on `-u`).
- Add the full path to the command (found via `which [command]` or searching the package's installed files with `dpkg` or apt/synaptic, etc.

---

Sounds like `timeout` behaves differently when it's run in an interactive terminal, vs in a script. Reading it's info page reveals an option I think you could use:

> ‘--foreground’
>       Don’t create a separate background program group, so that the
>        managed COMMAND can use the foreground TTY normally.  This is
>        needed to support timing out commands not started directly from an
>        interactive shell, in two situations.
>
> 1. COMMAND is interactive and needs to read from the terminal for
>            example
> 2. the user wants to support sending signals directly to COMMAND
>            from the terminal (like Ctrl-C for example)
>
>    Note in this mode of operation, any children of COMMAND will not be
>       timed out.  Also SIGCONT will not be sent to COMMAND, as it’s
>       generally not needed with foreground processes, and can cause
>       intermittent signal delivery issues with programs that are monitors
>       themselves (like GDB for example).

Comment: It doesnt work. Ive updated my question with my cron file. Also, the script is for productivity. Blocking access to the pc so I can take a break. I can change 10secs to 5min if I want to.

Comment: I've added some other ideas... but just voluntarily standing up and taking a break might be the easiest, or are you trying to force someone to take an unwilling break?

Comment: "The script is for productivity. Blocking access to the pc so I can take a break"  Consider a quiet, gentle, physical timer.  I'd say "egg timer" but those are pretty harsh.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage That's exactly what Wikipedia suggests on the linked [Pomodoro technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) page, *"The physical act of winding the timer confirms the user's determination to start the task; ticking externalises desire to complete the task; ringing announces a break. Flow and focus become associated with these physical stimuli."* I wouldn't want a loud fire-alarm heard-from-outside bell either, but a nice quiet musical one might be nice. This is SuperUser after all, and any sound clip could be used...